# How to fix traffic session table doesn't exists error?

Tags: python, sql, django

When I try to execute my code,I am getting this error? How could I resolve this issue?

```
ProgrammingError at /
(1146, "Table 'multi_traffic.django_session' doesn't exist")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'multi_traffic.django_session' doesn't exist")
Exception Location: C:\Users\USERNAME1\PYCHAR~1\SAMPLE~1\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py in query, line 277
Python Executable:  C:\Users\USERNAME1\PYCHAR~1\SAMPLE~1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.2
Python Path:    
['F:\\projects\\MULTI_TRAFFIC\\MULTI_TRAFFIC\\Code\\Multi_Traffic_Scene_Perception',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME1\\PYCHAR~1\\SAMPLE~1\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME1\\PYCHAR~1\\SAMPLE~1\\venv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME1\\PYCHAR~1\\SAMPLE~1\\venv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME1\\PYCHAR~1\\SAMPLE~1\\venv\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME 2\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME 2\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME1\\PYCHAR~1\\SAMPLE~1\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME1\\PYCHAR~1\\SAMPLE~1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you wrote this POST request or if it is a library or something. Could you please provide more info about it?

As the error describes, it seems that:

```
"Table 'multi_traffic.django_session' doesn't exist"
```

Make sure this table exists and it is available at the mentioned IP http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 0):

The table `django_session` does not exist.

You can run :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

To create all tables by running all django migrations, then restart your app and try running it again.